# Is there a way to move a kivy slider with button's and text box?

Tags: kivy

I have a project I would like to try and use kivy as a user interface.

The interface would have 1 slider 2 buttons and a text box. Basically the slider can be moved by sliding or finely incremented by the buttons. With a text box to read out the values but also able to manual enter a desired value.

I have googled around a bit and have not seen any examples of bonding all 3 inputs to 1 slider. I have only seen taking values from a slider and displaying it, I have no idea how to move a slider with a value.

Comment: can you write some runnable code describes what you have been tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


class CustomSlider(BoxLayout):
    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super().on_kv_post(base_widget)
        self.ids["button_less"].bind(on_press=self.on_button_less_click)
        self.ids["button_more"].bind(on_press=self.on_button_more_click)
        self.ids["text_input"].bind(text=self.on_text_input_changement)
        self.ids["slider"].bind(on_touch_move=self.on_slider_move)

    def on_slider_move(self, w, touch):
        self.ids["slider"].value = 5 * round(self.ids["slider"].value / 5)
        self.ids["text_input"].text = str(self.ids["slider"].value)

    def on_button_less_click(self, w):
        self.ids["text_input"].text = str(int(self.ids["text_input"].text) - 5)

    def on_button_more_click(self, w):
        self.ids["text_input"].text = str(int(self.ids["text_input"].text) + 5)

    def on_text_input_changement(self, w, value):
        self.ids["text_input"].text = self.get_value(value)
        self.ids["slider"].value = int(self.ids["text_input"].text)


    def get_value(self, value):
        if not self.isInt(value):
            return "0"
        value = int(value)
        if value < 0: return "0"
        elif value > 100: return "100"
        else: return str(value)

    def isInt(self, value):
        try:
            int(value)
            return True
        except:
            return False


class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<CustomSlider>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0
            max: 100
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: button_less
            text: "-"
        Button:
            id: button_more
            text: "+"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            input_filter: "int"
            text: "0"


CustomSlider:
```

Comment: This works wonderful thank you! The text box changes the slider value immediately as you start typing, can it be made to only change the value after hitting enter?

Comment: Yes it can but I'm gonna let you understand how to change my code to do so. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code

Kivy File:

```
Button:
    id: button_more
    text: "+"
    on_release: root.on_button_more_click()
```

Python File inside the CustomSlider class:

```
def on_button_more_click(self):
    self.ids.slider.value += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).